# What is the "Hang der Deutschen zur doppelten Abstraktion"?

Tags: literature, english

From the German translation of Philip K. Dick’s novel [VALIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VALIS) (bold by me):

> Doch ein weit grundlegenderes semantisches Problem liegt hierin verborgen: Angenommen, ich sage zu Fat oder Kevin sagt zu Fat: »Du bist Gott nicht begegnet. Dir hat sich nur ein Etwas offenbart, das die Qualitäten und Aspekte und die Natur und Kräfte und die Weisheit und die Güte Gottes besitzt.« **Das ist wie bei dem Scherz über den Hang der Deutschen zur doppelten Abstraktion.** Ein deutscher Experte für englische Literatur erklärt: »›Hamlet‹ wurde nicht von Shakespeare geschrieben, sondern nur von einem Mann namens Shakespeare.« Im Englischen (*›Hamlet‹ was not written by Shakespeare; it was merely written by a man named Shakespeare*) ist der Unterschied rein verbaler Natur und ohne Sinn, doch im Deutschen kommt er deutlich zum Vorschein (und das verrät etwas von den sonderbaren Eigenheiten des deutschen Gemüts).

I don’t get it. What is the difference between English and German here?

> - ›Hamlet‹ wurde nicht von Shakespeare geschrieben, sondern nur von einem Mann namens Shakespeare.
> - ›Hamlet‹ was not written by Shakespeare; it was merely written by a man named Shakespeare

Comment: I as a German native speaker don't get it either so I am curiously waiting for answer. I suspect however that this is somewhat subjective because as far as grammar and wording go I don't see a difference... hence the semantics should be the same, too

Comment: Ich denke, dass hier ein Missverständnis vorliegt. Philip K. Dick möchte meiner Meinung nach ausdrücken: „Unter den englischsprachigen Experten für Literatur sieht keiner einen Sinnunterschied, sondern nur rein sprachliche, die keiner Erwähnung wert sind. Es gibt aber einen deutschen Experten für Literatur, für den dieser Unterschied nicht nur rein sprachlich ist, sondern soviel Sinn enthält, dass er einer Erwähnung wert ist.“

Comment: @Toscho: Naja, Dicks Bezug auf "*... Eigenheiten des deutschen Gemüts*" verstehe ich schon als Allgemeinplatz. Aber darum geht es wohl in der hier vorliegenden Frage nicht.

Comment: @alk Natürlich ist das ein Allgemeinplatz. Zumindest aus dem zitierten Teil geht aber nicht hervor, wie Dick im konkreten Fall oder allgemein zu Allgemeinplätzen kommt. Möglicherweise hat er von der Äußerung dieses einen Experten gleich auf die ganze Sprachgemeinschaft geschlossen.

Comment: Ohne mich jetzt über das Werk informiert zu haben, wundert es mich, solche Zeilen in einem Roman außerhalb wörtlicher Rede o. Ä. zu finden. Kann es sein, dass der Autor hier nicht seine eigene Einschätzung, sondern diejenige eines anderen wiedergibt, die dann natürlich nichts mit der Realität zu tun haben braucht.

Comment: @falkb: Das war auch mein erster Gedanke

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Wieso spielt es eine Rolle, ob der Autor seine oder eine fremde Einschätzung wiedergibt? So oder so kann es mit der Realität zu tun haben oder nicht, oder sind Autoren unfehlbar?  Zumal der Autor hier ja nicht Shakespeare ist; nicht mals so hieß.

Comment: Ich höre davon zum ersten Mal. Könnte auf Hegel zurückgehen.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn ein Autor einen Charakter sprechen (oder denken, usw.) lässt, kann er ihm Worte in den Mund legen, die er als passend für den Charakter erachtet und die dann insbesondere nicht seine eigene oder überhaupt irgendwessen Einschätzung wiederspiegeln müssen. Wenn ich in einem Roman z. B. einen Astrologen auftreten lasse, kann ich ihm irgendwelchen Unsinn in den Mund legen, mit der er Astrologie zu begründen versucht. Dieser Unsinn muss dann nicht mit meiner Meinung und noch nicht einmal dem Unsinn, den reale Astrologen glauben, zu tun haben (und mit der Realität schon gar nicht.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Daraus, dass der Autor seine eigene Einschätzung wiedergibt folgt dennoch nicht, dass diese etwas mit der Realität zu tun habe. Auch Astrologen schreiben Bücher.

Comment: @userunknown: Wenn der Autor seine eigene Einschätzung wiedergibt (und man ihm Vernunft unterstellt), ist die Frage berechtigt, was ihn zu dieser Einschätzung veranlasst hat (und nichts anderes ist die Frage hier). Ist aus dem Zusammenhang ersichtlich, sollte zumindest die Möglichkeit in Erwägung gezogen werden, dass noch nicht einmal beabsichtigt wurde, dass dieser etwas mit der Realität zu tun hat.

Comment: Fehlt im letzten Satz etwas? `Ist aus dem Zusammenhang ersichtlich, dass ...` würde ich verstehen, oder was soll ersichtlich sein? Und woher die Geschlechtsumwandlung? Oben war es noch ein `die nichts mit der Realität zu tun hat`, jetzt ist es ein `dieser`. Dieser was?

Answer (score 6):

As noticed by rastafile, Dick's English novel does not contain a German translation of the sentence:

[image]

It therefore does not make much sense to compare the English and the German sentence and to discuss whether they mean the same thing (they certainly do). In my opinion Dick says that *forming a sentence like this* is a typical German phenomenon. I can only speculate what he "really" means, but I guess he wants to emphasize that Germans make a distinction between "signified" and "signifier". See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signified_and_signifier). I doubt that this is typical German, but it is Dick's poetic license to suggest this. Perhaps it also reflects an antagonism (as it is often claimed) between [German idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_idealism) and Anglosaxon rationalism.

PS. Everybody who knows Dick's oeuvre will confirm that he has some affinity to German language and philosophy. For example, the name of the protagonist in *Valis* is "Horselover Fat" which is the translation of "Philip" from Greek to English and of "Dick" from German to English.

It also seems that the translator of Dick's novel was not sure about Dick's intention and for that reason added the original English sentence.

Comment: He mentions god in the same thread. God is a very abstract device, without much concrete meaning. A manifestation of godlike powers are a concrete thing. So it's with "Shakespeare". A man named Shakespeare is more concrete than just "Shakespeare". At least it sound so to my ear, and moreso in German than in English. (<funny>Goethe & Schiller are excluded </funny>). Maybe Mr. Dick wanted to express that distinction between an abstract device and a concrete manifestation ? *shrug*

Comment: @a_donda Maybe you are right. Wouldn't that mean that Germans - in contrast to Anglosaxons - do not believe in the [duck test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test)?  "If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably **is** a duck." By the way, there is an American movie with original title "Beethoven". The German title is "Ein Hund names Beethoven" (A dog named Beethoven).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, both versions, English and German, are identical with regard to contents.

Second, there is no typical German liability to a double abstraction in general. I've never heard about that. Furthermore, we actually need to know what's exactly meant with double abstraction in the context of this German quotation.

Assumed there is any `doppelte Abstraktion` in the German quotation, the question is why we don't see it. Well, it's not clear from the question who and what has exactly been quoted, but, from what we know about the [authorship topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare#Authorship), likely the following could be meant as double abstraction: »... nicht von Shakespeare ... sondern nur von einem Mann, der sich Shakespeare nannte«, a Shakespeare who just called himself Shakespeare so to speak. But this is not used in the German sentence. The most logical explanation for that is for me: That special German quotation mentioned in that paragraph of the novel was not translated carefully enough back from its English translation to German, and that's why it has lost its original subtlety.

To get a more precise answer, you actually must find out what the real original German quotation is.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with äüö that it relates to the authorship question. The joke is that "a man named Shakespeare" is a non-answer to this question: Who wrote "Hamlet"? Was it Francis Bacon? Was it Shakespeare, the historically documented person? Was it Edward de Vere? Instead of answering the question by deciding which individual would fit best, the answer is given in form of an abstract description, that doesn't contain any information that is not already included in the question.
The same with Dick's own example: In  »Du bist Gott nicht begegnet. Dir hat sich nur ein Etwas offenbart, das die Qualitäten und Aspekte und die Natur und Kräfte und die Weisheit und die Güte Gottes besitzt.« a difference is made between "Gott" and "Etwas [...], das die Qualitäten und Aspekte und die Natur und Kräfte und die Weisheit und die Güte Gottes besitzt". But what meaningful difference could that ever be? The individual "God" is replaced by an abstract description, that actually includes a reference to God himself. Of course, it might be possible that there is more than one individual fulfilling that description, but since we aren't given any notion by which we might discern between any of them and the one of them that is 'actually' god the claim that it wasn't *the* God is completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

> I don’t get it. What is the difference between English and German
>   here?

**In the original the translation is missing.**

This is part one of the joke: to make a difference between "Shakespeare" and a man named "Shakespeare". What we actually are interested in is which man wrote the stuff, no matter if he himself (legally or not) or others called him "Shakespeare".

But the **translator** maybe was right to expose the english original:

"namens Shakespeare" ist not exactly "Shakespeare genannt"

But in English you can probably do similar things.

The "German" touch in this could be traditional philosophy (Kant,...), which can be very abstract.

> ...although German as a language will express the difference (...)

The author left it to translators to show how!

---

The context is clear: something with *powers and nature and wisdom etc. of God*, why not call it "God" for simplicity.

It is actually the well-known "...then it is a duck" rhetoric.

Comment: You, me initially too, and probably almost everyone else might be mistaken in assuming that *-ed* signaled strictly past participle. Wiktionary has it under etymology section 3 that *-ed* derived adjectives from nouns "without interveining verb", for one. It seems not to be related to \*-onts, see e.g. "friend", as I first had guessed, but I'm still not sure. It is anyhow not illuminating either that *namens* were simply from a "Genitive absolute form" of the noun. Anyhow, *namens* ~ *named* is a completely cromulent translation at least for sake of this particular translation, make no mistake

Answer (score 0):

Ich frage mich, ob hier nicht zwischen dem Phänomen Schein-Wirklickeit und dem der Abstraktion unterschieden werden sollte:

- Wie [äüö](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2987/%C3%A4%C3%BC%C3%B6) schrieb könnte jemand den Schein erwecken wollen, er sei Shakespeare, dh. er würde sich nur den Namen Shaespeare geben - eben zum Schein.
- Oder aber es ging Philip K. Dick’s umd die Abstraktion, dh. die die Idee dass eine Name nicht die Person ist, sondern nur der Hinweis auf eine echte Person.

Mein Eindruck und eine Antwort an den Fragesteller [unor](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1859/unor) - nicht P.K. Dick kennend sondern Englisch und Deutsch:

- Es gibt zwischen Englisch und Deutsch keine wirklichen Unterschiede was die Abstraktion angeht.
- Der Autor hat sich nicht klar ausgedrückt, ob es ihm um die Abstraktion geht oder um die feinen Unterschiede zwischen Schein und Sein, oder ob er wirklich beides zusammen nennen wollte.

___________________________ English translation below:

I wonder whether a distinction should not be made here between the phenomenon of illusory reality and that of abstraction:

- As [äüö](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/2987/%C3%A4%C3%BC%C3%B6) wrote, someone might want to give the impression that he or she is himself truly Shakespeare by naming himself so - to create the iilusion.
- Or Philip K. Dick's was concerned with abstraction, i.e. the idea that a name is not the person, but only the reference to a real person.

My impression and an answer to the questioner [unor](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/1859/unor) - not knowing P.K. Dick but English and German:

- There are no real differences between English and German as far as abstraction is concerned.
- The author has not clearly expressed whether he is interested in abstraction or in the fine differences between appearance and reality or whether he really intended to mention both ideas at the same time.

Comment: PS: I got here through the programming language Python and its "pass-by-object-reference"

Answer (score 0):

Es steht da recht deutlich, im Englischen sei "der Unterschied rein verbaler Natur". Nähert man sich von dort aus dem Vergleich zum Deutschen an, wird man also auch nur rein verbale Unterschiede finden. Das ist der erste Witz.

Nähert man sich dem aber von der deutschen Seite aus an und toleriere erstmal, selbst wenn man dem abgeneigt wäre, die Aussage darüber könnte stimmen, dann wird man im Englischen doch feststellen, dass der rein verbale Unterschied zumindest überflüssig und deshalb vielleicht unnatürlich und konstruiert klingt. Ob das im Deutschen vielleicht weniger zutrifft, mag dahinstehen, da es sich offenbar um einen Witz handeln soll. Deutsch ist jedenfalls berüchtigt dafür, in Film Synchronisation mehr Zeit pro Satz zu benötigen als die Vorlage und so den Übersetzern das Leben schwer zu machen.

Man möchte meinen, die Behauptung wäre etwa glaubhaft gemacht, ob des vermeintlichen Zitats eines deutschen Experten. In der Tat, es wirkt zumindest nicht unnatürlich. Gemeint war also, der Ausdruck sei typisch deutsch. Mithin fehlt es an relevanten Kriterien, ob qualitativ oder auch qualitativ, um diese offenebFeststellung zu etablieren. Auch das ist urkomisch.

Doppelt abstrakt--das ist abstrakt auch im Prädikat "Mann"; denn es mag zunächst naheliegen in Frage zu stellen, ob dies wirklich zutrifft; ob *Shakespear* nicht eher ein Autorenzusammenschluss war, manche mögen Ihn auch vergöttern. Dennoch wird die dritte Abstraktionsebene wohl mehr im Bereich der paranoiden Verschwörungstheoretiker anzusiedeln sein. Doch in der Gegenüberstellung zumindest des doppelten Kontrasts wird ein weiterer Witz deutlich, denn für Deutsche ist Shakespear nur irgendein weiterer wichtiger Autor, immerhin ein Mann, während schon allein der Name als Symbol für die Werke in der Englischen Literatur eine herausragende Rolle spielt.

Und auch auf Kulturhistorischer ebene wage ich einen Witz zu erkennen. Denn während Shake Spear den Seme-Semem Dualismus bald gänzlich aufzulösen wagt: "A rose is a rose is a rose"; Da hatte Luther erst kurz zuvor der heiligen Dreifaltigkeit neues Leben eingehaucht (was denn sonst für Schreibkram gepflefgt wurde, ist mir nicht wirklich geläufig).